# How to interpret slow query log information generated by MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-performance, mysql-slow-query-log

So my understanding of slow query log is that it logs info about all those queries that took >= time (in secs) that we have set in my.conf file.

Now lets take 3 cases of 3 different SELECT queries (against tables with INNODB engine):

**QUERY I:** Query_time: 32.937667  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 343  **Rows_examined:** 12714043

**QUERY II:** Query_time: 12.937667  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 43  **Rows_examined:** 714043

**QUERY III:** Query_time: 42.937667  Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 18  **Rows_examined:** 483

To me both QUERY I and QUERY II looks like possible cases of a bad query or poor indexing (or missing indexing) or fragmented table data etc. (anything else that I might have missed?) that user may look at to improve query execution time.

But for the QUERY III, I am not able to get my head around, I mean what could really be wrong with the DB that it takes 42 secs to just examine 483 rows and sent back 18 of them (with a negligble lock time). This becomes even more confusing when I see it happening intermittently.

So what I really want to ask here is:

- how should I interpret lock time info? Does it mean query had to wait for that many secs before it actually started executing? If yes, then in my example query III actually took 42 secs to examine 483 rows and sent back 18 of them?
- if lock time is neglible but still query time is super huge with just few hundreds of rows being examined and sent back, where should I start looking for issues?
- Could it be that query is spending to much time in some background IO activity? say logging or bin-logging.
- How badly could size of table affect the performance of query? e.g. can we say MySQL is good enough to handle table with 200+million rows
- Is there any better tool or way to monitor DB activity specially to figure background activity of DB? In short, to check where is that query spending most of it's time.

There might be lot many factors affecting such slow queries, so in case you feel that you need some more information from side to be able to help me then please do let me know.

Answer (score 28):

- **Lock time** is the time spend *before* the query starts executing.  I.e., time waiting for other threads to give up their locks on the data the current query needs to lock.
- **Query time** is the time to execute the query.  This may involve waiting for I/O if the rows aren't already in the buffer pool.  Repeating the same query for the same data may be faster, after the data is loaded into the buffer pool.

  If your query is sorting on disk for a given query, it'll be slower even if it examines few rows.

  If your I/O system is overtaxed, you can get intermittent slowness.  This also can happen to virtualized I/O (for example, cheap AWS instances).  Or also if your disks are starting to fail, they may get errors intermittently.

  Monitor **iostat** and watch the queue length, average wait, and service time.  See if there are periods of slowness, or if performance and throughput are more or less consistent.
- **Rows examined** does not reflect multiple I/O's needed to fetch a given row.  For example, if the row has a lot of big BLOB/TEXT/VARCHAR columns stored on overflow pages.  Or if the transaction needs to visit the rollback segment to fetch old versions of some rows, if they have been modified since this transaction began.

  Rows examined also does not tell us how complex are the expressions in your query.  You  could be calculating [Fibonacci sequences in stored functions](http://mtocker.livejournal.com/45222.html) or something crazy like that.

  Without seeing the queries and their EXPLAIN report, it's hard to make a generalization to explain the slowness, given only those numbers from the slow query log.

MySQL certainly can store 200 million rows in a table, but at that scale, you do start to get performance problems even when an index can reduce the search to 483 rows examined.  That is because the [depth of the B-tree index and size of an indexed column](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/the-depth-of-an-index-primer) directly relate to the number of I/O operations needed to look up those 483 rows.  The more I/O's, the longer it takes, and this is not reflected by rows examined.  The query time includes I/O time, but does not make clear how much of the query time is due to I/O.

A few other places to look for more detailed diagnostics are:

- [MySQL Performance Schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/performance-schema.html)
- [MySQL Query Profiler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-profile.html) (but note this is deprecated in favor of the Performance Schema)
- [Enhanced verbosity slow query log in Percona Server](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/slow_extended_55.html) reports the time a query spent waiting for I/O.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome answer.  What units does the `Query_time` use?  Seconds?  Milliseconds?

Comment: @JackM. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936593/what-is-the-unit-of-time-in-mysqls-slow-query-log

Comment: In case of single thread hitting inserts on table in sequential manner, lock time should be zero as no other thread is there to acquire lock. 
But I have seen lock time greater than zero

Answer (score 2):

Query_time: 12.937667 Lock_time: 0.000081 Rows_sent: 43 Rows_examined: 714043

```
Query Time: Total time including lock time query has taken

Lock_Time: Total query query was in a locked state

Rows sent: Total rows sent by server to client

Rows examined: Total rows scanned by a MySQL server for a query
```