# Extra large query_time in MySQL slow query log

Tags: mysql

If the unit of time in MySQL's slow-query log is second (according to [the SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936593/what-is-the-unit-of-time-in-mysqls-slow-query-log/6937160#6937160)), what does the following line from my MySQL's slow-query log mean?

> # Query_time: 18446744073709.550781  Lock_time: 0.000062 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 2

This request should take more than 500 years? ..

Comment: A quick Google search for `18446744073709.550781` suggests it's a recurring bug in MySQL Server.

Comment: Let us know when it finishes.  :-) :-)

Comment: @O.Jones It finished already! It's only that started when out-sourcing was handled to homo neanderthalensis' companies.